# How to run jQuery Application in React Application's Window

Tags: jquery, reactjs

What could be a nicest way to integrate and run jQuery Web Application in React based Application's "window", same Window where React Application is running?

We have a situation that jQuery Web Application should be integrated into React Web Application before is it ported and rewritten using React.

Any information considering this kind of issue?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Well, ideally you should not implement jquery in ReactJs as both of them are different Javascript frameworks having different execution patterns.

Before doing this you should have a basic idea of how jquery and reactjs manipulate DOM. To use jquery in ReactJs follow these steps:

1. Run `npm i jquery` and import it in your react component `import $ from "jquery";`
2. Now under the `useEffect` hook write your `jquery` code for that component.

[Check the sandbox for code snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-and-jquery-ehnls)

Comment: Yes, jQuery application will be rewritten using React but no immediately. What I was thinking that is it possible to run jQuery Application inside React Component etc. so that it's www pages are coming inside React Application. I think years a ago IFRAME was use to do that kind of things e.g. running Java WebApp inside ASP.NET WebApp but that is not suitable in React World if I have understood right.